# Changing Beginning of img

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

How to change the "*start*" of image?

I mean that the `img` is in the immobility only it's beginning is moving

I want change it **CSS** or **HTML**, in the last resort in **JavaScript**

Something like this: [FIRST PICTURE](http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/6550/v9mc.jpg) (This picture on click change it's beginnig).

... It transform to it: [SECOND PICTURE](http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/6550/v9mc.jpg)

Any idea? :/

Comment: FYR, both pictures are the same

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: We haven't the "crystal ball". Be more specific!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you might want to do CSS sprites.

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

If you want to change the image on click, you'll need some code.  I won't spend too much time on that, given your question is hard to decipher, but if it were me, I would create a class per sprite, then toggle between the two classes based on the click event.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="myImg"> </div>
<style>
.myImg{
 background: url('myimg.jpg');
}
.myImg2{
 background: url('myotherimg.jpg');
}
</style>
<script type="javascript/text">
$('.myImg').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('myImg');
    $(this).addClass('myImg2');
});
</script>
```

Ofcourse you'll have to use jquery link to get jQuery latest update.

So what have i actually done here?

I've used jQuery to check if user click div `.myImg` if he did i just switch bettwen the div's classes and each other class got different image.

Hope i helped.